# Possible masonry grid layout in Zurb Foundation 6

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am wondering if there a CSS tweak to make grid columns have masonry like layout.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
    <div class="large-6 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
    <div class="large-3 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No...there isn't. Other than CSS Grids (which aren't  really a thing yet), there is no CSS framework that can do this. It's just the way the layout model works. That's why masonry.js still exists.

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm with foundation v6.3.1 as well follow the code structure below:

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-4" id="masonary_container">
      <div class="column"> <!--Content Here--> </div>
      <div class="column"> <!--Content Here--> </div>
      <div class="column"> <!--Content Here--> </div>
   </div>
```

Then include masonry from: http://masonry.desandro.com/ and add at end of body tag.

```
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#blog_mason').masonry({
    itemSelector: '#blog_mason .column'
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works for me! I just had to change the IDs in the masonry function to match the ID in the html

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it with just CSS, but I found this article which referenced Foundation < 6 here: http://zurb.com/university/lessons/make-a-masonry-grid-responsive

Then I adjusted accordingly to fit Foundation 6 block grid. The new block grid no longer uses the ul > li structure and the classes changed names as well. Here is what I just now implemented:

```
<div class="row small-up-3 medium-up-4" id="container">
  <div class="columns"><img src="/images/img.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="columns"><img src="/images/img.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="columns"><img src="/images/img.jpg"/></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then include masonry from: http://masonry.desandro.com/ and add at end of html.

```
<script src="/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '#container div'
  });
});
</script>
```

Works like a charm! Note you will need to add some CSS to get your spacing right. You might consider using the "row collapse" class if you don't want any margins, or just add a margin-bottom to your div.columns

Comment: This article is NOT for Foundation 6, and it will not work for Foundation 6.

Comment: I know that's why it said "Foundation < 6" if you read the first line. And I adjusted it so that it would work in my project which does use 6. It does work.